# Trouble using simple SOAP call in ColdFusion, but works in php

Tags: php, soap, coldfusion

I've never done anything with SOAP and ColdFusion, so I have a feeling I may be overlooking something simple.  I've done quite a bit of reading and looked at examples online, but am not having any luck.

I have the following code in php that functions fine:

```
<?php

    ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled", "1");  

    $myDate = '09/05/2013 01:11am';
        $client = new SoapClient("https://www.domain.com/remote/service.svc?wsdl");
        $client->response_timeout = 60;//seconds
        //paramaters to the webservice
        $param=array("requestID"=>uniqid(),
                    "APIUser"=>"apiuser",
                    "APIKey"=>"apikey",
                    "pageCode"=>"pagecode",
                    "strDate"=> $myDate);
        $result = $client->AppointmentTimes($param); 

?>
```

In ColdFusion, I'm trying to replicate this functionality with the following code:

```
 <cfscript>
    stCust = StructNew();
    stCust.requestID = CreateUUID();
    stCust.APIUser = "apiuser";
    stCust.APIKey="apikey";
    stCust.pageCode="pageCode";
    stCust.strFromDate = "09/05/2013 01:11am";          
    checkTimes = CreateObject("webservice","https://www.domain.com/remote/service.svc?wsdl"  );
    availTimes = checkTimes.AppointmentTimes(stCust);
</cfscript>
```

The error that I'm receiving is:

```
Web service operation AppointmentTimes with parameters {{
    STRFROMDATE={09/05/2013 01:11am},
    APIUSER={apiuser},
    PAGECODE={pagecode},
    REQUESTID={0E6D4260-1143-300A-67B00B0F8203F795},
    APIKEY={apikey}
    }}
cannot be found.
```

I've reviewed the API documentation as well as the Java stubs, but can't figure out what I'm doing wrong on the ColdFusion end.

---

**edit:**  I've also tried the following approach after reading suggestions on Ben Nadel's blog:

```
<cfsavecontent variable="soap"> 
<cfoutput>  
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<soap-env:envelope xmlns:soap-env="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" 
                   xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" 
                   xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" 
                   xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" 
                   xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" 
                   xmlns:wsam="http://www.w3.org/2007/05/addressing/metadata" 
                   xmlns:tns="http://tempuri.org/" 
                   xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" 
                   xmlns:wsp="http://www.w3.org/ns/ws-policy" 
                   xmlns:wsap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/policy" 
                   xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
                   xmlns:msc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/12/wsdl/contract" 
                   xmlns:wsaw="http://www.w3.org/2006/05/addressing/wsdl" 
                   xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" 
                   xmlns:wsa10="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" 
                   xmlns:wsx="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/mex" 
                   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <soap-env:body>
        <tns:appointmenttimes xmlns:tns="http://tempuri.org/">
            <tns:requestid>
                5126adcc913f6
            </tns:requestid>
            <tns:apiuser>
                userid
            </tns:apiuser>
            <tns:apikey>
                apikey
            </tns:apikey>
            <tns:pagecode>
                pagecode
            </tns:pagecode>
            <tns:strdate>
                09/05/2013 01:11am
            </tns:strdate>
        </tns:appointmenttimes>
    </soap-env:body>
</soap-env:envelope>
</cfoutput>
</cfsavecontent>
<cfdump var="#soap#">
<cfhttp url="https://www.domain.com/remote/service.svc" method="post" result="httpResponse">
  <cfhttpparam type="header" name="content-type" value="text/xml"> 
    <cfhttpparam type="header" name="SOAPAction" value=""> 
    <cfhttpparam type="header" name="content-length" value="#len(soap)#"> 
    <cfhttpparam type="header" name="charset" value="utf-8"> 
    <cfhttpparam type="xml" name="message" value="#trim(soap)#">  
</cfhttp>
<cfdump var="#httpResponse#">
```

and receive the following:

```
struct
Charset     [empty string]
ErrorDetail     [empty string]
Filecontent     Bad Request
Header  HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request 
Content-Type: text/html 
Date: Wed, 04 Sep 2013 08:29:03 GMT 
Cache-Control: private 
X-AspNet-Version: 2.0.50727 
Content-Length: 11 
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
Mimetype    text/html
Responseheader  
struct
Cache-Control   private
Content-Length  11
Content-Type    text/html
Date    Wed, 04 Sep 2013 08:29:03 GMT
Explanation     Bad Request
Http_Version    HTTP/1.1
Server  Microsoft-IIS/7.5
Status_Code     400
X-AspNet-Version    2.0.50727
Statuscode  400 Bad Request
Text    YES
```

Comment: If you dump the object without trying to call it's method, what happens?

Comment: a dump of checkTimes shows the object of org.tempuri.BasicHttpStub, with the a list of methods in the structure.

Comment: I usually end up using Ben Nadel's approach. One thing I noticed is that you are submitting the `content-length` header as the length of `soap` but you are submitting the `message` as the `trim` of `soap`. Try changing your `content-length` header to this: `<cfhttpparam type="header" name="content-length" value="#len(trim(soap))#">`. Also, since you are note making use of the `SOAPAction` header I would remove it completely instead of passing it as an empty string.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion Miguel.  I've tried changing the content-length and removing the soapaction header and am still receiving the same bad request response.

Comment: The only other thing I noticed is that you are not calling out the `AppointmentTimes` function in your `cfhttp` approach.  Not sure if that should be your `SOAPAction` or otherwise defined in the URL. You will need to read over the API for that info. The only other recommendation I can give is to use [SOAPUI](http://www.soapui.org/)  (or something similar) to debug the service call.  Once you get it working with that you can convert over to ColdFusion.

Answer (score 0):

Comparing the Parameters in PHP and ColdFusion where the error lies, there is a difference with the parameters being passed in.

In PHP you have 'strDate' with ColdFusion you have named it 'strFromDate', perhaps rename the ColdFusion param to 'strDate'.

Comment: good catch jbuda.  However, I changed it to strDate in the coldfusion code and am still receiving the same error.

Comment: Have you tried dumping out checkTimes to ensure that the webservice is being created properly. writedump(checkTimes)

Comment: Another thought, are the webservice parameters case-sensitive? If so, try the square bracket notation markup.

`stCust['requestID'] = CreateUUID();
stCust['APIUser'] = "apiuser";
stCust['APIKey'] ="apikey";
stCust['pageCode'] ="pageCode";
stCust['strDate'] = "09/05/2013 01:11am"; `

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I just tried that and it looks like it's creating it correctly.  in the dump, it is showing the method I'd like to call as appointmentTimes(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String)

Comment: I'm not sure if they're case-sensitive, I've replaced the code with bracket notation and am still receiving the same error.

Answer (score 0):

What version of ColdFusion are you using?
Because in 10 (possibly 9)
You can set the version of the web-services (Axis) library that is used.

I have ALWAYS had issues with web-services if i do NOT specify a WSVERSION of 1.
I am yet to get version 2 to work in any or my CF code.

Lastly, we use the MX unit testing framework for unit testing and it also doesn't support version 2, either.

So it is just habit now to ensure that we have the version set to 1.
You can do this in the CFIDE, or on a CFC by CFC basis with the "wsversion" component parameter.

Comment: FYI, it only applies to CF10 ([when Axis 2.x support was introduced](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/10.0/Developing/WSe61e35da8d318518-2fbb29ff1353e865893-8000.html))

Comment: Thanks for the info.  I'm using cf 9.  Does that mean if this webservice is using axis 2, that it is incompatible?

Comment: If you're using CF9 - then you do not need to worry about the CF server using Axis v2. CF9 ONLY uses Axis v1.